# MVC how to submit multiple files using one submit button and in Controller retrieve the input file name

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I hope my title is understandable. I will try to be as clear as possible. So here's what I am planning to do. I have a Customer Info page which they can upload their documents, in the page, there is two input files which they can upload their documents and then the moment they click submit, I want to fill the Photo and PassportNo variable with the path string so I could retrieve the file later.

What I am struggle with currently is that I manage to upload the files to the system, but I am kinda stuck with updating the filePath into the Photo and PassportNo properties. I can update one of them however I dont know how to retrieve two Input Files. What I meant is that, when the Form Submit, I dont know how to retrieve which type of Input Types are coming from the form (Photo or Passport No).

I want to retrieve the "name" from the Input to the Controller, so in the Controller I can do something like "If its coming from the "name", then do certain update". Hope I am clear enough, if there are other suggestion please feel free to suggest.

Thanks!

Customer Model

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Photo { get; set; }
public string PassportNo { get; set; }
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFiles", "Customer", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype= "multipart/form-data"}))
{
<input type="file" name="Photo" />
<input type="file" name="PassportNo" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload Files" />

}
```

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadFiles(HttpPostedFileBase Photo)
    {
      if (Photo.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var filename = Path.GetFileName(Photo.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Files/"), filename);
                Photo.SaveAs(path);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("FileForm");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

just add second parameter to the action

public ActionResult UploadFiles(HttpPostedFileBase Photo, **HttpPostedFileBase PassportNo**)